# Typing warning: pylance "str" is incompatible with "list[Literal]"

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing, python-dataclasses, pylance

Why pylance can't reconnize that I am assigning a literal in this case

```py
Color = Literal["blue", "green", "white"]


@dataclass
class TestColor:
    my_color: Color | list[Color]


color = TestColor(my_color=["blue"])
color.my_color = color.my_color[0]
```

The error is on `color.my_color[0]` that raise a pylance warning:

```
"str" is incompatible with "list[Color]"
"str" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['blue']"
"str" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['green']"
"str" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['white']"
```

But the value of `color.my_color[0]` is obviously of type Color !
Should I just ignore or should I raise an issue somewhere ?

Comment: "Should I just ignore or should I raise an issue somewhere?" Neither. "The value of color.my_color[0] is obviously of type Color !" no, it isn't. You are confusing *runtime* with *compile time*. Generally when you write literals with no annotations static analysis tools like mypy will infer the most generic type, which here for `["blue"]` is `List<str>`. You could stuff it in a var with a Color annotation, and then it would probably work. But you seem to possibly want an enum: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the value of color.my_color[0] is obviously of type Color !

That's actually not true. Pylance doesn't remember the line with `color = TestColor(my_color=["blue"])`. For pylance `type(color.my_color) == list[Color] | Color`.

Now what is if `color.my_color` is actually `Color` and not `list[Color]`?
Well, you'd access the first character of one of the color strings.

Aka: pylance 'fears' `color.my_color[0]` is just `b`, `g` or `w` (which clearly *isn't* of type Color).

The logic in pylance, why it says `[0]` is string, is:

- if `color.my_color` is `list[Color]` then `[0]` is of type `Color`.
- if `color.my_color` is `Color` then `[0]` is of type `str`.
- The most common type between `Color` and `str` is just `str` - so `color.my_color[0]` is of type `str` - which isn't assignable to `Color` (and also not to `list[Color]`)

So you need to ensure `color.my_color` is actually a list to make pylance happy.

```
Color = Literal["blue", "green", "white"]


@dataclass
class TestColor:
    my_color: Color | list[Color]


color = TestColor(my_color=["blue"])
assert isinstance(color.my_color, list)
color.my_color = color.my_color[0] # no more complaints
```

Comment: That's the information I missed ! It can be a string and that's why It raises a warning, thanks ! :)